# JavaScript foreach statement to append entire records

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have following JavaScript code that used to append the entire records to MySQL table.

```
$('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
  '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
  '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id 
  + '">' +
  '</td>' +
  '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].unit_price + '"></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus type="number" step="any" id="discount_price[]" name="discount_price[]" ></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i> 
   </td>' +
'</tr>');
```

But the above function only append the first record to the table. How to change the code with foreach statement to append the entire records.I used Codeigniter framework.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forEach like this:

```
jData.data.forEach(data => {
  $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
    '<td ><span id="product" >' + data.item_name + '</span>' +
    '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + data.item_id 
    + '">' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="text-center">' + data.qty + '</td>' +
    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + data.qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +
    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + data.unit_price + '"></td>' +
    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus type="number" step="any" id="discount_price[]" name="discount_price[]" ></td>' +
    '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i> 
     </td>' +
  '</tr>');
})
```

Comment: @ Jacek Rojek. No. The item stopped selecting qty & unit_price

Comment: @mcode is your `jData` valid and consistent? Edit: i think i know what was wrong, updated

Comment: @ Jacek Rojek. Yes jData valid & consistent. My original code is appending the first record correctly.As you said, your updated code couldn't appear. var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

Comment: @ Jacek Rojek. </td> tag of your code should be in the line. Then the code is correct. '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +

Answer (score 0):

You accesing only to  jData.data[0].*  (just the first index element)

you need  an iteration eg: based on a index i and then accessing by

```
 jData.data[i].qty ,
 jData.data[i].unit_price,
 ....
```

Comment: @ scaisEdge. Can you change my code as per your suggestion.

Comment: @mcode  i can't change the code properly without know  how you have obtained the jData.data  array ..so  you sould update your question and add  also this code too.. anyway  i see there already a valid answer ..  try using  the suggestion by JaceyRojek ...